# How to build Docker images quicker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm currently building a docker image and running the container to run some tests in it for a Python application I'm working on. Currently the Dockerfile copies the files over from the host machine, sets the working directory to those copied files, runs a `sudo apt-get` and installs pip, and finally runs the tests from `setup.py`. The Dockerfile can be seen below.

```
FROM ubuntu

ADD . /home/dev/ProjectName

WORKDIR /home/dev/ProjectName

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip && \
    python3 setup.py test
```

I was curious if there were a more conventional way to avoid having to run the `apt-get` and `apt-get install pip` every time I'd like to run a test. The main idea I had was to build an image with pip already on it, and then build this image from that one.

Comment: Adding to the accepted answer, any time you want to make changes to your Dockerfile but want to minimize building time, add the changes to the end of the Dockerfile so that Docker reuse as much cache as possible. Docker will rebuild from the first line that changes are made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker builds using cached layers if it can. By adding files you have changed it invalidates the cache for all subsequent rules. Put the apt commands first and those will only be run the first time you build. See [this blog](http://blog.tutum.co/2014/10/22/how-to-optimize-your-dockerfile/) for more info.

Comment: Hi @Kurt Stutsman, the link to the blog post is no longer available, could you update the link or include a summary from that post to your answer, please. Thanks.