# Can i mount volumes while building Docker image?

Tags: docker

I'm working on Chromium fork docker builder image. I'd prefer to mount some volume for build cache. Is it possible while **buiding** of an image (`docker build -t mychromiumfork_builder .`)?

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Adjust env
ENV SRC="/mychromiumfork/src" OUT="/mychromiumfork/out" GOOGLE_PLAY_AGREE_LICENSE="1" LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" CHROME_DEVEL_SANDBOX="1"
 # here i'd like to add `ENV CACHE="/mychromiumfork/cache"`

# Install Chromium build dependencies.
RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list # && dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qy \
    git \
    build-essential \
    clang \
    curl \
    lsb-core \
    sudo \
    --no-install-recommends

RUN mkdir -p ${SRC}

# gclient sync prerequisites
COPY .gclient /mychromiumfork
RUN touch /mychromiumfork/.gclient_entries

# Copy sources
COPY src ${SRC}

# required to skip modal dialog with user confirmation (button click required)
RUN echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
RUN chmod +x ${SRC}/build/*.sh
RUN ${SRC}/build/install-build-deps-android.sh --no-prompt \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get autoremove -y

# Install Chromium's depot_tools.
ENV DEPOT_TOOLS /home/developer/depot_tools
RUN git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git $DEPOT_TOOLS
ENV PATH $PATH:$DEPOT_TOOLS
RUN echo -e "\n# Add Chromium's depot_tools to the PATH." >> .bashrc
RUN echo "export PATH=\"\$PATH:$DEPOT_TOOLS\"" >> .bashrc

VOLUME ${OUT}
# here i'd like to add `VOLUME ${CACHE}`

RUN cd /mychromiumfork && gclient sync # here i'd like to add `--cache-dir ${CACHE}`
WORKDIR ${SRC}

#RUN gn gen --args='target_os="android" is_debug=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding="Chrome"' ${OUT}/Debug
#CMD ninja -C ${OUT}/Debug chrome_public_apk
```

To be used like this:

```
docker build -t mychromiumfork_builder . # i'd like to pass -v ${PWD}/cache:/mychromiumfork/cache
docker create -v ${PWD}/out:/mychromiumfork/out --name mychromiumfork mychromiumfork_builder /bin/true
docker run -it --volumes-from=mychromiumfork mychromiumfork_builder
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not available at the moment. Currently volumes can only be mounted onto a running container and not an image.

Check this [open issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14080) for more info.

Comment: any workarounds or best practises to solve it are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache frequently repeated operations to make the build faster, then the recommended approach is to push the least frequently changing commands towards the top of the Docker file, and the more frequently changing files towards the end of the file.

You can always divide and conquer by building the top part of the Dockerfile on its own, lets tag it 'my_cache_build:latest' and then splitting off a second dockerfile that has

```
FROM my_cache_build:latest
..
```

that way you can cache part of the docker build such that it takes no time when you repeat the part which changes often.

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#run

[How to build Docker images quciker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379631/how-to-build-docker-images-quciker?rq=1)

Comment: it looks like it's another caching: not caching of docker layers create on previous steps but caching some build data between creating of images (not related to docker).